# Check if ServiceHost is alive

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a NetNamedPipeBinding with a bool isAlive() method with which i want to check if the ServiceHost is alive.

Currently this looks like this:

```
 while (!stopThread)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000); 
            try{
              try
              {
                 pipeproxy.isAlive();
              }
              catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException)
              {
                 pipeproxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
              }
            }                
            catch (EndpointNotFoundException)
            {

               //Show notification
                  stopThread=true;
            }
            catch{}
        }
   //Close Application
```

Surprisingly i can create a Channel even though there is no host, so I'm not sure whether this is the correct approach or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as the service that is referenced in `pipeFactory` is available, you can create new channels from it.  The proxy could be faulted independent of the service.

Comment: So what is the proper way to do a isAlive check?

Comment: Why you need to check if its alive ? Register the Faulted state on the ServiceHost. i assume it is hosted in managed application, make sure all your service calls are with try/catch, and do not throw in the catch, send back a fault contract.

Answer (score 3):

CreateChannel does not connect to the service, this only happens when you call it.